# Set Maven's pluginGroups at Command Line

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

Is it possible to set Maven's pluginGroups property via the command line?

I know it's possible to set in the `settings.xml` file as [documented here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html), but I'd really like to pass it as a parameter on certain jobs.

To be clear what I mean, this is what I'd have to stick in `settings.xml`:

```
<pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>com.mycompany.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is configuration parameter - so it is hard to define. Try to create file with alternative setting and call maven:

`mvn -s alternativaSettings.xml <goals>`